# How to bind a specific property in a DataTemplate independent of ItemsControl in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol, itemssource

I have following DataTemplate

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="iconButtonsTemplate">
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="120,50,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
                <icon:IconButton   Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ButtonClickCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding Path=CommandParameter}"    TextContent="{Binding TextContent}" ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}"
                                   IsIconButtonVisible="{Binding Path=MyLocalBoolList}"  />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

And I have also ItemsControl such that ,

```
     <ItemsControl Width="2400"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding IconConfigList}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource iconButtonsTemplate}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      </ItemsControl>
```

So is it possible to bind my IsIconButtonVisible property to ViewModel independent from IconConfigList in ItemsControl.

Comment: Why do you have this property when there is `Visibility`? Also i have no idea what your last sentence (and the question for that matter) is supposed to mean.

Comment: My visibility is also related with an special animation in IconButton. My purpose is to handle IsIconButtonVisible for each icon during runtime. So I want a separate list to update  IsIconButtonVisible  properties for each icon

Comment: That information belongs in the items of the IconConfigList, why would you separate it?

Comment: I want to separate because , loading whole list is so heavy and unnecessary. And also , during runtime , I just wanted to update IsIconButtonVisible properties.  (  I have tried in IconConfigList , but it was so slow , I have to fasten )

Comment: I suspect that you are doing something wrong if that was slow...

Comment: Yeah you may right , but we will use that code on slow ATM machines. There is a  cost of 1-2 seconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ElementName value in your binding.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="iconButtonsTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="120,50,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >
        <icon:IconButton Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ButtonClickCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding Path=CommandParameter}"    TextContent="{Binding TextContent}" ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}"
                     IsIconButtonVisible="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyLocalBoolList, ElementName=ItemsControlName}"  />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

If ElementName doesn't work for you, then try RelativeSource.

Answer (score 0):

```
IsIconButtonVisible="{Binding Path=DataContext.ViewModelProperty,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: what is the type of your VM property that you want to bind this Property with?